# shell script : for loop on list of files

Tags: string, shell, for-loop, filenames

I have a folder with lots of files and I want to perform an action with some of the files. I have files "BlaBla_01.mat", "BlaBla_02.mat" up to "BlaBla_11.mat"

```
{ time mpiexec -n 40 ./runex @alg.param BlaBla_01.mat; }
```

--> this generates 2 output files. I need to rename and move them...

```
mv FirstOut.log My/Folder/Results/FirstOut_BlaBla_01.log
mv NextOut.log My/Folder/Results/NextOut_BlaBla_01.log
```

How do I make this in a for loop so that the files are processed and renamed as they should?

I have tried:

```
NUMS='01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11'
for i in $NUMS;
do
FILENAME="BlaBla_"$i".mat"
{ time mpiexec -n 40 ./runex @alg.param $FILENAME; }
mv FirstOut.log "My/Folder/Results/FirstOut_BlaBla_"$i".log"
mv NextOut.log "My/Folder/Results/NextOut_BlaBla_"$i".log"
done;
```

and many variants of it, but it does not work.

I am sorry this must be a very easy question but I am not a programmer so this is my first week on shell scripts

Thank you in advance,

have a nice weekend

Seb

Comment: What about that loop didn't work? (Also generally avoid `ALL_CAPS` variable names as they are "reserved" for the shell.)

Comment: for starters, you can leave the `$i` inside the double quotes

Comment: The best way to deal with this would be to have the `runex` program create the output files in the correct location with the correct name.  If it is under your control, fix it.  If it isn't, say so.  Does the `mpiexec -n 40` command run 40 copies of the program on the same file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NUMS='01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11'
for i in ${NUMS[@]};
do
FILENAME="BlaBla_"$i".mat"
{ time mpiexec -n 40 ./runex @alg.param $FILENAME; }
mv FirstOut.log "My/Folder/Results/FirstOut_BlaBla_"$i".log"
mv NextOut.log "My/Folder/Results/NextOut_BlaBla_"$i".log"
done;
```

Comment: No, `NUMS` is not an array. It happens that `${NUMS[0]}` returns the whole string, and because it's not quoted, you can iterate over the words of the string. No advantage over just `$NUMS`

Answer (score 0):

I would write that as

```
for root in BlaBla_{01..11}; do
    time mpiexec -n 40 ./runex @alg.param "$root.mat"
    mv FirstOut.log "My/Folder/Results/FirstOut_$root.log"
    mv NextOut.log "My/Folder/Results/NextOut_$root.log"
done;
```

Requires bash for the brace expansion